# Is it possible to disable Spring's @Async during integration test?

Tags: java, spring, cucumber-java

I have a method annotated with @Async say

*@Async 
public void createArticles(long Id){}*

but I'm just trying to a cucumber test of that method. Is it possible to test it synchronously?

Comment: Create a configuration without `@EnableAsync`.

Comment: I cant. Is a project from job and should remain with @EnableAsync

Comment: You can... Create a test configuration or simply override the task executor with a `SyncTaskExecutor`.

Answer (score 13):

Create your async configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "async.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class SpringAsyncConfig {
    // Your configuration here
}
```

the annotation `@ConditionalOnProperty` here will create this bean if only the configuration value `async.enabled` is `true`

Then in the configuration file if you are going to run the integration test you can set the value to false

`async.enabled = false`

or if you are using Spring profiles you can always set the value to `true` in other profiles configuration files like `application.properties`, `application-dev` and set to `false` in `application-integration.properties`